# How to subtract/ perform arithmetic with an xarray dataarray and an xarray dataset?

Tags: python-xarray

**DISCLAIMER**: First of all this is my first ever question on stackoverflow, so I am not really comfortable with posting properly formatted code and output.

Basically I have an xarray dataset with dimensions {'time': 360, 'lon': 135, 'lat': 129}, with multiple variables, from which I want to subtract a dataarray which has the exact same named dimensions {'time': 360, 'lon': 135, 'lat': 129}.

When I subtract the two I just get all nans produced. Is there anyway I can perform arithmetics between an xarray dataset and an xarray dataarray?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This sounds like a great question, but a little more info would make it much easier for us to help. There's a great answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) that shows how to post code, and a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a good question. Specifically, to answer this question, some more information about the variables in the datasets would be helpful. Could you print out the two objects you're trying to subtract and add those to the question?

Comment: Without knowing what the contents of your Dataset and DataArray are, it's hard to answer this question. But my first guess would be that the coordinates aren't matching. I'd check to make sure that all of your coordinates are the same type (e.g. if you have string time objects on the dataset and pd.datetime objects on the dataarray, the result would be as you describe). Also make sure that there aren't small numerical differences between the coordinates. You could always test this explicitly with, e.g. `np.isin(arr.time, ds.time).all()`